Quillen equivalence induced by right transfer
Suppose (M,Fib,Cof,WE) is a model category, and $B$ a bicomplete category.
Given adjunctions $U\dashv K$, $F\dashv U$ respect to which $B$ admits a model structure $B_l$ and $B_r$ from left and right transfer, I'd like to prove that $B_l$ and $B_r$ are Quillen equivalent, i.e $FU(x) \to y$ is a weak equivalence if and only if $KU(f)\circ\eta_x$ is.
Trying to solve this exercise I've stumble across hovey's book which essentially give an equivalent statement for an adjunction to be Quillen equivalence (Proposition 1.3.13)
(Unfortunately) in my context $F$ of Hovey is the composition of $FU$ and $U$ of Hovey is the composition of $KU$.
Having proved that $(FU,KU)$ is a Quillen pair I can establish that bottom-right-arrow and right arrow are weak equivalences, so that $(FU,KU)$ is a Quillen equivalence if and only if $U_{rFX} \circ \eta_x$ is a weak equivalence.
How could I proceed from this? Any help would be appreciated.
Edit: I think that in the context of Hovey $R$
of an object is a fibrant replacement.

In general I'm not sure you can say too much, but I'll give some conditions for when the two model structures will be Quillen equivalent via the identity functor, and I'll give an example to show that your suggested adjunction $(FU, KU)$ needs not be a Quillen equivalence (in fact, this is a quite mild example, so I would expect this rarely is the case)
First, let's recall that the left transferred model structure on $B$ via $U \dashv K$, denoted $B_l$, has as cofibrations and weak equivalences $U^{-1}(cof)$ and $U^{-1}(w.e.)$, respectively. Dually, the right transferred model structure on $B$ via $F \dashv U$, denoted $B_r$ has as fibrations and weak equivalences $U^{-1}(fib)$ and $U^{-1}(w.e.)$ respectively. For the rest of this, let's assume both model structures exist.
In general, the identity needs not be left Quillen $B_r \to B_l$. This will hold if and only if, for every cofibration $i : a \to b$ in $B_r$, $Ui$ is a cofibration in $M$. At first, this may seem lengthy to check, but in practice, one typically transfers cofibrantly generated model structures using one of the existence theorems listed on nlab, section 3 (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/transferred+model+structure). In these cases, the transferred model structures are themselves cofibrantly generated. If this holds, then for any set $\mathcal{I}$ which generates the cofibrations of $M$ under the small object argument, the set $F\mathcal{I}$ is a generating set for the cofibrations in $B_r$. Thus, $id: B_r \to B_l$ will be left Quillen if and only if $UF\mathcal{I} \subseteq cof$ in $M$. This won't always hold, but it holds in the case of (unenriched) projective and injective model structures on $Fun(C, M)$ for a small category $C$ (in the enriched case, one needs some mild assumptions regarding tensors and cotensors on $M$ for this to hold).
Now, to see that $(FU, KU)$ needs not be a Quillen equivalence (although this will always be a Quillen adjunction), let us work with the arrow category of $sSet$, $sSet^\to$. This is equivalently, for $C = a \xrightarrow{f} b$ the "free-standing arrow" (i.e. $f : a \to b$ is the only nonidentity arrow in $C$), the functor category $Fun(C,sSet)$. Let $obC = a \coprod b$, the discrete category with two objects $a$ and $b$, and let $i : obC \to C$ be the obvious inclusion. Then there are adjunctions

So $F = Lan_i$, $U = i^*$, and $R = Ran_i$. Now, $Fun(obC, sSet)$ has the model structure where $f : X \to Y$ is a (cofibration/fibration/weak equivalence) if and only if it is so pointwise (i.e. $fc : Xc \to Yc$ is a (cof/fib/w.e.) for each $c \in obC$). In this case, the left transferred model structure is the injective model structure, $Fun(C,sSet)_{inj}$, and the right transferred model structure is the projective model structure, $Fun(C, sSet)_{proj}$. Both of these model structures indeed exist. The adjunction we are interested in is the following:

To show that this is not a Quillen equivalence, I'll use the characterization Def 1.3.12 in Hovey's book: a Quillen adjunction $L : C \rightleftarrows D : R$ is a Quillen equivalence iff for any cofibrant $X$ in $C$ and fibrant $Y$ in $D$, a map $LX \to Y$ is a w.e. iff $X \to RY$ is a w.e.. So our $L$ is $Lan_ii^*$ and our $R$ is $Ran_ii^*$, and we will need to pick an injectively cofibrant $X$ and projectively fibrant $Y$ (note: this is just pointwise (co)fibrant). Most choices will give a counterexample here. Here's an example:
Take $X$ to be the constant diagram at $\Delta^0$, $id:\Delta^0 \to \Delta^0$. This is injectively cofibrant (in fact, every diagram is). Here, $Lan_ii^*X$ is the first inclusion $i_1:\Delta^0 \hookrightarrow \Delta^0 \coprod \Delta^0$. This is projectively fibrant because $\Delta^0$ is a Kan complex, so we can take $Y = Lan_ii^*X$ and $f : Lan_ii^*X \to Y$ to be the identity. Note that $f$ is clearly a w.e.. Then $Ran_ii^*Y$ is the diagram $id : \Delta^0 \coprod \Delta^0 \to \Delta^0 \coprod \Delta^0$, and the corresponding map $\hat{f} : X \to Ran_ii^*Y$ is the square

Where the horizontal arrows form $f$. This is clearly not a weak equivalence (since $i_2:\Delta^0 \to \Delta^0 \coprod \Delta^0$ is not a Kan equivalence). So this is not a Quillen equivalence, but note that these two model structures are Quillen equivalent via the identity functor, as I mentioned before.
